# Hive histogram_numeric function outputs invalid character

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I am using histogram_numeric function of hive and I want to output my select query to file.
However I get invalid characher in file and i cannot use it for plotting the data.

here is my code:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/home/cloudera/queries/histograms/q1'
      ROW FORMAT DELIMITED                                                           
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','                                                       
     select explode(histogram_numeric(operationTime,30)) from transaction;
```

And as a result I get :

```
3.1968591661070107"someInvalidCharacter"196572.0
14.41629947203365"someInvalidCharacter"725191.0
27.84241052482667"someInvalidCharacter"27069.0
```

But I expect "," instead of "someInvalidCharacter".

What can be the problem

Answer (score 1):

Per the Hive [LanguageManual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF), `histogram_numeric` creates an array of structs.  Trying using `inline` to "explode" your output instead of using `explode`.